# How to load item in simple adapter using async task?

Tags: android, performance, listview, asynchronous, android-adapter

I load songs from sd card, Initially it takes time to load in listview, that too in certain mobile the application itself stopped. So, I planned to load with help of Async task.
Watched several videos, which explained using Array Adapter, since here I'm using Simple adapter, I don't know how to incorporate with Async task, I deeply thank for the any suggestions to work app in a faster.

**There are two parts that confuses where to apply Async task:**

1. ***It scans the sd card for .mp3 files and load in list.***

   public class SongsManager {
       // SDCard Path
       /*final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
               .getPath() + "/Download";*/
       private ArrayList> songsList = new ArrayList>();

   ```
   //final ArrayList<File> mySongs = getPlayList(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

   // Constructor
   public SongsManager(){

   }

   /**
    * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
    * and store the details in ArrayList
    * */
   public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(File root){

       final SongsManager context =  this;
       //File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

       //File[] files = home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter());
       File[] files = root.listFiles();    // All file and folder automatic collect
       if ( files!=null && files.length > 0)
       {
           for (File file : files) {

               if (file.isDirectory()) {
                   scanDirectory(file);
               } else {
                   addSongToList(file);
               }
           }
       }
       else
       {
           return null;
           //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       // return songs list array
       return songsList;
   }
   private void scanDirectory(File directory) {
       if (directory != null) {
           File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
           if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
               for (File file : listFiles) {
                   if (file.isDirectory()) {
                       scanDirectory(file);
                   } else {
                       addSongToList(file);
                   }

               }
           }
       }
   }

   private void addSongToList(File song) {
       HashMap<String, String> songMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
       try {
           // Adding each song to SongList
           if (accept(song)) {
               songMap.put("songTitle",
                       song.getName().substring(0, (song.getName().length() - 4)));
               songMap.put("songPath", song.getPath());
               songsList.add(songMap);
               System.out.println(songMap);
           }
           else{
               System.out.println("invalid song:"+song.getPath());
           }
       }
       catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
   }

   public boolean accept(File song) {
       return (song.getPath().endsWith(".mp3") || song.getPath().endsWith(".MP3"));
   }
   ```

   }
2. ***Listview with Simple adapter.***

   if(utils.songsList!=null && utils.songsList.size()>0) {
                   // looping through playlist
                   for (int i = 0; i < utils.songsList.size(); i++) {
                       // creating new HashMap
                       HashMap song = utils.songsList.get(i);

   ```
                   // adding HashList to ArrayList
                   songsListData.add(song);
               }

               // Adding menuItems to ListView
               adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
                       R.layout.playlist_item, new String[]{"songTitle"}, new int[]{
                       R.id.songTitle});


               setListAdapter(adapter);
   ```

please suggest me how to do this with Async task or any other go.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are two ways make an interface eg InterfaceBack, activity/fragment implements it, pass this to constructor of CustomAsyncTask and on post execute use call the InterfaceBack method abc(List a) and do what you want.  or 2. use AsyncTask in the Activity/Fragment and call method on postexecute